# Using Foreach item on my tabpages doesn't get any change

Tags: c#

I have a tab control with 4 tabpages inside:
I need to use for loop for each item inside on each TabPage.
Code below it doesnt change any thing to me.

```
foreach (Control c in SubMenuTabControl.Controls)
{
   if(c is Label)
      c.Text="Hello";
}
```

Comment: Does `SubMenuTabControl.Controls` contain any objects that meet the `is Label` condition?  When you debug, what objects do you loop over?  Are they they objects you expect?  Are any of them `Label`s?

Comment: Yes. If i will use SubMenuTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls, it works but only with my selected tab page

Comment: Try replacing `c.Text = "Hello"` with `Console.WriteLine("Label");` and run your code. Check if your console contains "Label". If it does not, you do not have any `Label` in your array.

Comment: @Dim: Then it sounds like `SubMenuTabControl.Controls` *doesn't* contain the controls you think it does.  So what *does* it contain?  Are there any other properties on `SubMenuTabControl` which enumerate control objects?  Do the controls *within* `SubMenuTabControl.Controls` contain the actual controls you're looking for?  You need to examine this information in a debugger, don't just program blind.

Comment: It seems that it doesnt work for child elemnts. Even i use foreach (Control c in this.Controls) Console.WriteLine(); It doesnt shows me anything

Comment: `tabControl` contains `TabPages` and therfore you need to a nested `foreach` loop to get inside the tab and into your labels

Comment: Guys create a project with a tab control and try to use foreach loop in this.Control. You will see that elements inside tabcontrol can't find them

Comment: @styx you have right! But i dont want to create 4 loops foreach my page. Is there any code for contain all my tabpages at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two iterations, one of the tab pages of the tab control, and then one on the controls of the tab page itself.

For example:

```
foreach (TabPage tab in SubMenuTabControl.TabPages)
{
    foreach (var control in tab.Controls)
    {
        var label = control as Label;
        if (label == null) continue;
        label.Text = "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i said in my comment `tabControl` contains `TabPages` and therefore you need to a nested `foreach` loop to get inside the tab and into your `labels`

```
 foreach (TabPage tabControl in SubMenuTabControl.Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control item in tabControl.Controls)
                {
                    if (item is Label)
                       //your logic here
                        item.Text = "Hello";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

for serverside asp.net controls:

```
foreach (Control c in controlToCheck.Controls)
            {
                if (c is Label)
                    ((Label)c).Text = "Hello";
            }
```

for html label

```
foreach (Control c in controlToCheck.Controls)
            {
                if (c is LiteralControl)
                    ((LiteralControl)c).Text = "Hello";
            }
```